# How to fix a "java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection" exception in HTTPClient on .NetStandard

Tags: android, xamarin, httpclient, .net-standard

I have been scratching my head with this one for a while. I'm building an Android app in Xamarin and I have a login POST request that mostly works, but will occasionally recieve this error. I notify the user and tell them to try again but I am still getting the error far too often and want to fix it so the app provides a smoother experience.

Here is the stack trace I have logged on App Center:

```
LoginProvider+d__1.MoveNext () C:\source\repos{MyApp}{MyApp}{MyApp}\Services\LoginProvider.cs:35
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{testclarity.i-menzies.com:443, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=62.244.173.166 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:905)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:789)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:443)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:501)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:200)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
```

I am using .NETStandard 2.0, with Xamarin Forms 3.2.0.871581.

I have scoured most of Google and identified that this is an issue with various Android libraries, especially OkHttp (the same one mentioned in my stack trace). I've tried investigating the .NETStandard source on Github to identify the possible cause, but I find the project very difficult to navigate, especially as this problem seems to be Android specific. **Any advice on finding the right source would be ideal.**

Things I have tried based on suggestions from the internet:

- Setting my connection header to closed.
- Setting my transfer encoding
  to chunked.
- Swapping out the Android HttpClient implementation from
  Android to Default in the Android project's properties.

These seem to be among the popular suggestions online, some of which work for people, some of which don't.

Another common suggestion is setting the OkHttp library's configuration to OkHTTP.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(true), which apparently fixes the problem for many people, as suggested here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1517#issuecomment-144069139.

Also, a similar bug seems to have been filed in Xamarin.Android here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41100. But this has been marked as fixed. I'm not sure whether this would feed into my Xamarin Forms project.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem or how I can investigate further beyond what I've already tried?

Comment: Try avoiding the OkHttp stack by using the Managed HttpClientHandler along with the BoringSLL SSL.TLS implementation, at least then if it is a client issue (i.e.the keep alive timing) and not a server issue (the server is closing the keep alive socket connection) (Also what is the keep-alive timeout set to on your server?, And can you increase it?)

Comment: @SushiHangover - I am going to experiment with Managed HttpClientHandler and BoringSLL, as you recommended. I will need to check with my team about the keep-alive time on the server as I am not sure how this is set up. Thank you for the suggestions, I will report back as I want to help out any Xamarin devs who might run into this same problem!

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: Hi @NathanCrama. Following on from SushiHangover's helpful suggestion, I switched my Android project over to the Android Client implementation instead, as detailed in this post here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2651#issuecomment-457644819. I haven't seen the problem since doing this.

Comment: Alright thanks. I was hoping for something a bit better since Microsoft doesn't seem to encourage going down that route, according to this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos , but thank you for your answer nevertheless.

Comment: On the contrary, based on the link you provided, it appears Microsoft are actively encouraging using the Android Client configuration as I am doing:

April, 2018 

"In order to ensure your apps continue to work with these servers and services, you should update your Xamarin projects with the Android HttpClient and Native TLS 1.2 settings shown below, then re-build and re-deploy your apps to your users."

Answer (score 5):

After following the information in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos

And changing my HTTPHandler to the native android handler:

> The Xamarin.Android HttpClient configuration is in Project Options >
>   Android Options, then click the Advanced Options button.
>
> These are the recommended settings for TLS 1.2 support:
>
> Visual Studio Android Options
>
> [image]

The one extra bit I missed was:

> Projects must reference the System.Net.Http assembly.

Make sure your project references **System.Net.Http** otherwise it will still use OKHttp

Answer (score 3):

You can just go the Android Project > Properties > AssemblyInfo.cs file.
Open the AssemblyInfo file and add the following line at the end:

[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]

This helped me solve my problem. I hope it helps you also

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and been tracing for this fix. My project reference
to System.Net.Http.
I was changing my HTTPHandler to the native android handler when I got this exception but getting kinda similar system exception when using a different HTTPHandler.
I tried a lot of suggestions and finally fixes the issue by using https in my base URL. Here's my reference: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1517#issuecomment-560486265

IMO, the fix might be different in each case, so you might want to try other suggestions.